# How can i show A is independent of B in probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

Hello I have a question

For a family with three children, the following events are defined:

A = {all children have same gender}

B = {there is at most one boy}

Show that A is independent of B.

I know independence relation but I couldn't implement to this?

Comment: Some context is needed.  What is the entire sample space and what is the experiment?  Is there a large pool of children, and $A$ and $B$ subsets chosen randomly from that pool?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot write some informations. I will edit question.

Comment: You need to show $P(A) \cdot P(B) = P(A \cap B)$, which boils down to computing these three probabilities and verifying this equation holds. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the experiment consists of producing three children.  Consider all the possible outcomes, genderwise:

1. BBB
2. BBG
3. BGG
4. GGG

The first nuance I am unclear about is, Are these considered equally probable?  Or, by contrast, does it matter *in what order* the children are born (so, for examaple, BBG and GBB would be different outcomes, even though both have the same number of boys)?

If the above four outcomes are equally probable, i.e. each has probably 1/4, then
$$P(A) = P(BBB) + P(GGG) = 1/2,$$
and
$$P(B) = P(GGG) + P(BGG) = 1/2,$$
and
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(GGG) = 1/4.
$$

Comment: Good answer! Thank you. I am new player in probability theory. This was easy question. :( I spent your time. Again, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad to help.  [This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=PS8lQQ8AOHYC&dq=sadovsky+discrete+mathematics+google+books&source=gbs_navlinks_s) contains a chapter on probability, specifically written for newbies.